# Why no encoder when mapping lines into Array[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark is giving me a compile time error

```
Error:(49, 13) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    .map(line => line.split(delimiter))
        ^
```

For the following code

```
val digital2 = sqlContext.read.text("path").as[String]
    .map(line => line.split(delimiter))
    .map(lineSplit => {
      new MyType(lineSplit(0), lineSplit(1), lineSplit(2), lineSplit(3)
        , lineSplit(4).toInt, lineSplit(5).toInt, lineSplit(6).toInt, lineSplit(7).toInt
      )
    })
```

However this code works just fine

```
val digital = sqlContext.read.text("path").as[String]
    .map(line => {
      val lineSplit = line.split(delimiter)
      new MyType(lineSplit(0), lineSplit(1), lineSplit(2), lineSplit(3)
        , lineSplit(4).toInt, lineSplit(5).toInt, lineSplit(6).toInt, lineSplit(7).toInt
      )
    }
```

I'm not following what is going on.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `.map(line => line.split(delimiter))` will returns `Dataset[Array[String]]`. Then it requires an encoder for `Dataset[Array[String]]`. However, such encoder was added in 1.6.1. So if you use old Spark versions, it cannot compile.